# Rasa Install ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:

Tags: python, rasa

So I am trying to install rasa with

```
pip install rasa
```

I have python version 3.9.0

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: <directory>
```

Please help me I have no idea whats going on!

Comment: Please include the complete error message

Comment: What's your OS?